# LDAP query not working

Tags: python, email, filter, ldap

I'm really running out of ideas.

I recently was assigned to improve a script we have in Python so that it can fetch all users whose email match a string (more exactly, all the users whose email match with the value obtained from a HTML's text input).

It works well by using this filter ("search" is the text obtained from the text input):
`user_filter = '(mail=%s)' % search`

but it needs for the email value to be exactly so it can match with the user's email, and what I need is to match any written down value(string).

The last filter I used was this:
`user_filter = '(mail=*%s*)' % search`

and also like this:
`user_filter = '(mail=%s*)' % search`

(please notice the use of wildcards)

but none of them worked.

Any ideas who can I achieve this? Do you need more context?

I'm using *ldap* and function *search_s*

This is a snippet of the code:

```
def ldap_query(query):
""" returns the members of an LDAP group """

try:
    ldap_conn = ldap.initialize(LDAP_URL)
    ldap_conn.timeout = LDAP_TIMEOUT

    ldap_conn.simple_bind(LDAP_USERNAME, LDAP_PASSWORD)

    if not ldap_conn.whoami_s():
        raise Exception('503 Unable to authenticate to LDAP server with master user & password')

    res = ldap_conn.search_s(LDAP_BASE_DN, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, query)

    if res == []:
        raise Exception('Group not found in LDAP directory, using filter {}'.format(query))

    print res
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
print ldap_query('(mail=my.name@mycompany.com)')
```

but if I use the wildcards, I ended up with the error:

```
print ldap_query('(mail=a.name*)')
```

**EDITED**
just now it started to work, by using the last filter (the one just above here). Dunno why it didn't work before.

Comment: Please provide the shortest possible complete program that demonstrates the error. See [mcve] for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked well by using just one wildcard:

```
'(mail=a.name*)
```

rather than two:

```
'(mail=*a.name*)
```

I used that approach because of what I've seen while working with MysQL "LIKE" query %string%, whereas with LDAP filters seems not to be the case.

Comment: It should work both ways, but the leading wildcard will be slow, as it requires a full search, just as wth LIKE. Try not to have to use it.

Comment: will trying again with both wildcards to make sure it works (or at least make it work), maybe there is still something missing (on my code).